# XNA Content.Load() Memory Usage

Tags: c#, windows, graphics, xna

In XNA, when calling Content.Load() to load in a resource, if you load the same resource into multiple objects (i.e. the texture for a projectile of which there can be many) are you getting a copy for each object, or is the system just internally referencing the same memory for each one?

I was realizing that having a separate Texture2D object in each item may be a memory issue down the line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ContentManager will cache the object and return the reference to that object when you try to load it again.

Comment: So, if I load into a Texture2D in 2 different objects and then modify the texture data in one, does it get changed for both of them?

Answer (score 3):

Yes modifying the texture data will change all textures that reference that data.

If you need multiple ones then duplicate the original file and load different versions.

Comment: hmm not an ideal solution ... no way to copy the object structures data in memory?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to make a new Texture2D object and simply copy the changed data into the new texture with the SetData method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.setdata.aspx